# Group and count with null group key

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig script that generates some statistics for page views. Here's a snippet:

```
pageview_content_age_tmp = 
  FOREACH pageviews GENERATE ((1398816000000L-created)/86400000L)/7L as age;
pageview_content_age = 
  FOREACH pageview_content_age_tmp GENERATE (age>6L?6L:age) as age;
content_created_hist = 
  FOREACH (group pageview_content_age by age) GENERATE group as age, 
  COUNT(pageview_content_age) as count;
content_created_hist_sorted = ORDER content_created_hist by age;
dump content_created_hist_sorted;
```

This generates a histogram of the age of pages viewed (`created` is the timestamp when the content was created), e.g.,

```
(,0)
(0,8873)
(1,6701)
(2,9868)
(3,6466)
(4,12593)
(5,4971)
(6,51520)
```

The first row `(,0)` corresponds to the null key. However, it turns out that the result is wrong, i.e., the number of page views associated with the null key is much higher than 0 (that's caused by missing data, which is fine).

According to [the documentation for version 0.10.1](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.1/basic.html#nulls_group), the relation `group pageview_content_age by age` should group together all page view records corresponding to the null key together since it's grouping a single relation, but something is breaking along the way. I wonder if it's the previous relation that squashes all data with age > 7 together that's messing things up. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` ignores null values. You are looking for [`COUNT_STAR`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#count-star).

Comment: I eventually figured that out but kudos for the catch.